# PrimeFaces nested form inside p:dialog with appendTo="@(body)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, nested-forms, jsf-2.2

I have this fragment:

```
<h:form id="form">

    <!-- other content -->

    <p:panel id="panel" header="test">
        <p:inputText id="input1" value="#{viewScope.prop1}" required="true" />
        <p:commandButton id="button1" process="@form" update="@form @widgetVar(dialog)"
            oncomplete="PF('dialog').show()" value="ok" />
    </p:panel>

    <!-- other content -->

</h:form>

<p:dialog id="dialog" header="dialog" widgetVar="dialog" modal="true">
    <h:form id="form2">
        <p:inputText id="input2" value="#{viewScope.prop1}" required="true" />
        <p:commandButton id="button2" process="@form" update="@form" value="ok" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

and all is working as expected.

What I'd like to achieve is this:

```
<h:form id="form">

    <!-- other content -->

    <!-- fragment start -->
    <!-- this fragment will be on its own file and included via ui:include (or inside composite component) -->
    <p:panel id="panel" header="test">
        <p:inputText id="input1" value="#{viewScope.prop1}" required="true" />
        <p:commandButton id="button1" process="@form" update="@form @widgetVar(dialog)"
            oncomplete="PF('dialog').show()" value="ok" />
    </p:panel>

    <p:dialog id="dialog" header="dialog" widgetVar="dialog" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)">
        <h:form id="form2">
            <p:inputText id="input2" value="#{viewScope.prop1}" required="true" />
            <p:commandButton id="button2" process="@form" update="@form" value="ok" />
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
    <!-- fragment end -->

    <!-- other content -->

</h:form>
```

but I unsuccessfully tried some combination of `process` and `update` for `button1` resulting in process anything... `input1` is even resetting...

So, how to build a `p:dialog` that can be shipped inside a fragment or a composite comp and that is excluded from outside `form`?

Note that using:

```
<h:form id="form">

    <!-- other content -->

    <ui:include src="panel.xhtml" />

    <!-- other content -->

</h:form>

<ui:include src="dialog.xhtml" />
```

is not an acceptable solution.

I'm on JSF 2.2.8 (mojarra) and PF 5.1

Comment: I guess its not acceptable to start the include with </h:form> and end with <h:form> ? :) Seems to me you'll get nested forms no matter what

Comment: no, it isn't allowed :) however i'm not trying to avoid nested forms, i'm trying to make them work with the help of appendTo attribute. according to PF dialog docs this should be possible.

Comment: But isn't the nested forms what gives you trouble? I always expected it would be unnested in the outputted html through appendTo. There is some discussion on primefaces forum about it, maybe you can find something there

Comment: Try using the form name instead of @form

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you nest html forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a way using **OmniFaces**, with `<o:moveComponent />` :

page:

```
<h:form id="form">

    <!-- other content -->

    <ui:include src="/fragment/with/inner/form.xhtml" />

    <!-- other content -->

</h:form>
```

fragment:

```
<ui:composition>    
    <p:inputText id="outerText" value="#{viewScope.text}" />

    <p:commandButton id="openButton" process="@form" update="@widgetVar(testDialog)"
        oncomplete="PF('testDialog').show()" value="open" />
    <o:moveComponent id="move" for=":#{facesContext.viewRoot.clientId}" destination="ADD_LAST">
        <h:form id="innerForm">
            <p:dialog id="dialog" widgetVar="testDialog" header="test dialog">
                <p:inputText id="innerText" value="#{viewScope.text}" />

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton id="confirmButton" process="@form" update=":form"
                        oncomplete="if(!args.validationFailed) PF('testDialog').hide()" 
                        value="submit" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
    </o:moveComponent>
</ui:composition>
```

This will cause some warning:

```
WARNING Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'form:innerForm:dialog' because the UIComponent cannot be found
WARNING Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'form:innerForm:innerText' because the UIComponent cannot be found
WARNING Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'form:innerForm:confirmButton' because the UIComponent cannot be found
```

because the restored components are not re-removed on subsequent `RESTORE_VIEW` for postback.

These warnings, as for my experiments, are harmless and could be safely ignored.

However I opened [a pull request](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/pull/224) to eventually fix it.

Answer (score -3):

Only use one form inside of dialog. Work fine for me.

```
<h:body>

<h:form id="OneFormId">
    <!-- Some content -->
</h:form>

<p:dialog id="MyDialogId" header="My Header Info"
    widgetVar="MyWidgetVarName" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)">
    <h:form id="MyFormId">
        <p:outputPanel>
            <p:messages id="MyMsgId" autoUpdate="true" />
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel for="usr" value="User:" />
                <p:inputText id="usr" value="#{MyManageBeanName.MyProperty}"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="User is required." />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <p:separator />
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:commandButton value="Save" id="MyBtnSaveId"
                    styleClass="ui-priority-primary" icon="ui-icon-circle-check"
                    process="@form" />
                <p:commandButton value="Cancel" id="MyBtnCancelId"
                    onclick="PF('MyWidgetVarName').hide()"
                    styleClass="ui-priority-primary" icon="ui-icon-close"
                    process="MyBtnCancelId" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>

<h:form id="OtherFormId">
    <!-- Some content -->
</h:form>
```