# Binding values to UIInput in composite component results in null

Tags: jsf, primefaces, composite-component

I am trying to create a composite component for a user search. Here is the component xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<cc:interface componentType="searchUser">
    <!-- Define component attributes here -->
    <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.lang.Object"
                  shortDescription="Selected User"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <p:commandButton onclick="PF('sdgl').show();" type="button" value="search for user"/>
    <p:dialog header="Search for User"
              widgetVar="sdgl"
              modal="true"
              width="80%"
              appendTo="@(body)"
            >
        <h:form id="searchDLGForm" >
            <p:fragment autoUpdate="true">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="searchPanel">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Username: "
                                   for="username"
                            />
                    <p:inputText id="username" binding="#{cc.login}"/>

                    <p:outputLabel value="First Name: "
                                   for="firstname"
                            />
                    <p:inputText id="firstname" binding="#{cc.firstname}"/>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Last Name: "
                                   for="lastname"
                            />
                    <p:inputText id="lastname" binding="#{cc.lastname}"/>

                    <p:commandButton value="search" actionListener="#{cc.search}"/>
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:dataTable value="#{cc.foundUser}" var="user" id="sdgl_res" selection="#{cc.selectedUser}"
                             rowKey="#{user.id}">
                    <p:column selectionMode="single"
                              style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
                    <p:column headerText="First Name">
                        #{user.firstName}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Last Name">
                        #{user.lastName}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="E-Mail">
                        #{user.email}
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:fragment>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</cc:implementation>
```

The compnent is nesten in:

```
<h:form id="ouMembers">
    <div>
        <p:panelGrid>
            ......
            <my:searchUser id="searchDLG" value="#{ouBean.userToAdd}"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

And the corresponding Java:

```
private UIInput firstname;
private UIInput lastname;
private UIInput login;
private UserModel selectedUser;
private List<UserModel> foundUser;


 /**
 * Returns the component family of {@link UINamingContainer}.
 * (that's just required by composite component)
 */
@Override
public String getFamily() {
    return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
}


/**
 * return selected user
 *
 * @return selected user
 */
@Override
public Object getSubmittedValue() {
    return selectedUser;
}

public void search(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("searchUser called with: " + this.login.getSubmittedValue()+ ", " +
            ""+this.firstname.getSubmittedValue()+"," +
            ""+this.lastname.getSubmittedValue());

    this.foundUser = UserModel.searchUser((String)this.login.getSubmittedValue(),
            (String)this.firstname.getSubmittedValue(),
            (String)this.lastname.getSubmittedValue());
}

@Override
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    UserModel value = (UserModel) getValue();
    if(value!=null){
        firstname.setValue(value.getFirstName());
        lastname.setValue(value.getLastName());
        login.setValue(value.getLogin());
    }else{
        firstname.setValue("");
        lastname.setValue("");
        login.setValue("");
    }
}

+ getters setters
```

The problem I currently have, is that `this.login.getSubmittedValue()`, `this.firstname.getSubmittedValue()` and `this.lastname.getSubmittedValue()` are null in the search method. I have tried using `getValue()` but that also resulted in null value.

I am following http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html tutorial for this. Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks.

I am using: 
com.sun.faces 2.2.12 
primefaces 5.2
on Glassfish 4.1.0

**EDIT**

After removing the `<h:form id="searchDLGForm" >` and the `appendTo="@(body)"` from the dialog, it works. however I have to remove the `modal="true"` parameter, or the dialog is also inactive.

Comment: Looks like you're nesting forms, which is illegal in HTML. A [real MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) should quickly point out the cause.

Comment: As I had `appendTo="@(body)"` it should not be within a nother form. When i removed the `appendTo` I had to remove the form because of that. (will update question to prove some more information about nesting and versions.)

Comment: this question might be related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603894/primefaces-5-1-nested-form-inside-pdialog-with-appendto-body

Comment: ok after some more research, this is what I found: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20655 and it corresponds to what I am seeing. No `<form>` tag when dialog is appended to body and has its own `<h:form` tag inside. However withoud `appendTo="@(body)` the `modal=true` will not work.