# The warning of "Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'j_idX' because the UIComponent cannot be found" occur, with using CombinedResourceHandler

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, omnifaces

I get the warnings of below once, when I submit and update="@form".

```
14:03:23,139 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application.view] (default task-27) Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'j_id2' because the UIComponent cannot be found
14:03:23,139 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application.view] (default task-27) Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'j_id3' because the UIComponent cannot be found
```

**But removing "org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler" from faces-config.xml, the warnings dosen't get.**

Developing enviroment is ...

- Primefaces 7.0
- Omnifaces 3.4
- WildFly 16.0.0.Final

Here is minimum sample.(but my production code is more complexity, so many(20-1000) the warnings get.)

**index.xhtml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<f:metadata><f:viewAction action="#{indexView.init()}"/></f:metadata>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="mainForm">
        <p:messages id="messages"/>
        <p:panelGrid id="panelGrid" columns="3" layout="grid">
            <p:outputLabel id="labelInput1" for="@next" value="input"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="input" value="#{indexView.selectOne}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{indexView.itemCandidates}" var="i" itemLabel="#{i}" itemValue="#{i}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:commandButton id="btn" value="submit" process="panelGrid" update="@form" actionListener="#{indexView.submit}"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**IndexView.java**

```java
package com.sample.primafaces_operation_verification;

import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import // omitted // ;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class IndexView implements Serializable {

    @Getter
    private List<String> itemCandidates;

    @Getter @Setter
    private String selectOne;

    public void init() {
        this.itemCandidates = List.of("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd");
    }

    public void submit() {
        Messages.addGlobalInfo("Selected item : {0}", selectOne);
    }
}
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
              version="2.0">
    <application>
        <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
        <action-listener>org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener</action-listener>
        <navigation-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
        <view-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler</view-handler>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.MOVE_SCRIPTS_TO_BOTTOM</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>
        <param-value>6</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
        <param-value>6</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.omnifaces.VIEW_SCOPE_MANAGER_MAX_ACTIVE_VIEW_SCOPES</param-name>
        <param-value>6</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.faces</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I expect not getting the warnings.
How can i fixt it?

Comment: Can you try 3.4.1-SNAPSHOT to see if it's fixed for you?

Comment: @BalusC Thank you for fixing it. I tried 3.4.1-SNAPSHOT, I was able to confirm that the warning disappeared. I think this(https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/527) issue can be closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found several references to this warning but not a duplicate on SO worth voting to close your question as duplicate, so I'll attempt to answer by citations:

[PrimeFaces nested form inside p:dialog with appendTo="@(body)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36067035/865107)

**Michele Mariotti** says:

> These warnings, as for my experiments, are harmless and could be safely ignored.
>   However I opened [a pull request](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/pull/224) to eventually fix it.

---

BootsFaces [issue 325 Unable to save dynamic action with clientId 'j_id...'](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/325#issuecomment-200046844)

**stephanrauh** commented on 22 Mar 2016

This is a warning, not an error. As soon as you set the ProjectStage to production, the warning is gone. So I consider this a minor nuisance, not a serious error. In any case, do you get the warning without using OmniFaces?

**stephanrauh** commented on 22 Mar 2016

Unlikely. The warning occurs when you manipulate the JSF DOM tree using the wrong API. For instance, by removing a resource file by simply deleting it from the list. That's what OmniFaces used to do in an earlier version. JSF detects that something's missing, gets nervous and reacts with omitting these confusing warnings. It's possible that BootsFaces uses the "forbidden" API, but I believed to have fixed that. In any case, can you upload a simple project that reproduces the warning? This make our job a lot easier.

---

**To conclude** the warning is triggered by `org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler` removing resources from the view which is part of it's core functionality. Try setting `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` to `Production` and ingore the warning while coding.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I will ignore during development.